# import external bootstrap css is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
.bootstrap {
    @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js");
}
```

This is not working. Any ideas? Is there a way to debug this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use @import only in css file

```
 @import url("stylesheetB.css");
```

so in your case

```
 @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

for js files use the `script` tag

```
 <script src=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
```

visit [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) under css to get familiar with bootstrap classes and grid

That means the full HTML structural elements

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />-->
  <style>
  @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
   
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
<!-- header content goes in here -->
  </header>

  <nav>
<!-- navigation menu goes in here -->
  </nav>

  <section id="sidebar1">
<!-- sidebar content goes in here -->
  </section>

  <section id="main" class=container>
<!-- main page content goes in here -->
  </section>

  <aside>
<!-- aside content goes in here -->
  </aside>

  <footer>
<!-- footer content goes in here -->
  </footer>
 <script src=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I use it in HTML <style type="text/css"></script>

Comment: @nofear87 please see the code snippet on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
 @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js");
```

Why wrapping into a `boostrap{}` ?

Comment: Becuase I want that Bootstrap is only available in this class

Comment: Do you use CSS preprocessors ?

Comment: You can only imbricate proprieties by using a preprocessor, like SASS, you should try use them, because it's not allow to have kind of namespace in CSS. Hope i'm clear

Comment: Yes, I think so...and what should I change in the sass to get it only working for bootstrap class?

Comment: I'm not sure about the fact that you can do an import like this, butif it work,  it will work with the code just like you posted in the answer